# How to protect my anonymity and authenticity in Irc?

Tags: authentication, irc

I use irssi for playing multiplayer/programming game with random people. Some people take the game a bit too seriously so I want to protect my identity in it. I do not want that someone misuses my identity or someone starts tracking my locations. The game is a JavaScript -game.

1. How can I protect my anonymity in irc?
2. How can I protect cookied information on my machine?
3. Even if I have registered to the irc server, how can I let other people to verify my identity like GPG-verified emailing?

*Please, add label `"anonymity"`.*

Comment: Decentralized? What are you trying to secure? Your computer, your chats over the wire? An IRC server?

Comment: @Caleb: sorry I am newbie in this topic. I am just interested what does it mean to have an Irc in paranoid mode? Probably many kind of security/encryption methods or? Like if I am playing a multiplayer game and I would not like to reveal my location when using irc to communicate -- any way to protect my identity with irc?

Comment: @hhh “How to secure X” on its own is meaningless. You need to say what you want to secure against who (“what assets to protect against what threats”). E.g. you might want to keep the content of the messages secret from unauthorized users (confidentiality), or to make sure your messages aren't silently modified by others (integrity), or to ensure someone else can't pass of as you (authenticity), or to ensure people can't deny having posted a message (non-repudiability), or to hide your identity from other participants (anonymity), etc. From your comment, I guess authenticity or anonymity?

Comment: @Gilles: thanks, good explanation! Corrected my question.

Comment: @hhh That's much better, but you might still want to explain more. Anonymity and authenticity are kind of contradictory: one means no one knows who you are, the other means everyone knows who you are. Maybe you want authenticity, but for a virtual identity (a pseudonym) that others shouldn't be able to associate with your real one? For anonymity on the Internet, [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) is the obvious answer (that's if you want to be anonymous to the IRC server; it may be overkill if you trust the IRC server but want anonymity towards other participants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many IRC networks offer connections via SSL/TLS. This encrypts the connection between you and the server in the same fashion as websites using HTTPS.

IRSSI supports connecting over an SSL-secured connection, [see here](https://docs.indymedia.org/view/Sysadmin/IrssiHowTo) for how to configure it. Refer to the server host's FAQ or documentation for the port(s) and server(s) on their network which accept SSL connections.

Comment: Note that unless all connections between individual servers in an IRC network are SSL enabled, your communication might be sent in plaintext over some link at some point.  You can rectify this by using server-local channels (prefix room names with "&") instead of network channels ("#") if I recall correctly.